# Charts in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, charts, oracle-apex

Hi everyone I wanna ask u about how I can bring data last 24 hours into bar charts, is there any   methods to make it please
I have this table without data

| datetime | clientchannel | servicename | service_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13_02_2022 9:35 | ***** | notification | 2 |

Answer (score 1):

It is a `WHERE` clause you need, I presume. Something like this:

```
select ...
from your_table
where datetime >= sysdate - 1;
```

---

Why? Because - when you subtract a number from `DATE` datatype value in Oracle - it subtracts that many *days*.

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> select sysdate right_now,
  2         sysdate - 1 yesterday
  3  from dual;

RIGHT_NOW           YESTERDAY
------------------- -------------------
13.02.2022 11:01:34 12.02.2022 11:01:34

SQL>
```

---

If you store date values as strings (which means that `DATETIME` column is declared as e.g. `VARCHAR2(20)`, and that's really bad idea), then you first have to *convert* it to a valid `date` datatype value - use `TO_DATE` function with appropriate format mask:

```
where to_date(datetime, 'dd_mm_yyyy hh24:mi') >= sysdate - 1
```

---

**[EDIT]** If you want to go 60 minutes back, then subtract that many minutes:

```
SQL> select sysdate right_now,
  2         sysdate - interval '60' minute an_hour_ago
  3  from dual;

RIGHT_NOW           AN_HOUR_AGO
------------------- -------------------
14.02.2022 07:09:30 14.02.2022 06:09:30

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank u a lot , I will try this method

Comment: If I want the data hourly , before 60 min it’s possible or what ??

Comment: Yes, it is. Have a look at edited answer.

Comment: That’s good thank u a lot

Comment: Something else if I want to refresh automatically with this , I mean I need refresh automatically and bring the data from this hoour and before one hour u got it what I mean

Comment: When I use these method it bring data and it look like static doesn’t change or update so I need method with this to refresh the data

Comment: What would you want to refresh? This query returns data related to "right now" (value returned by the SYSDATE function). If you want to see data e.g. 10 minutes later, you'd have to re-run that query. In other words, "refresh". Perhaps you could use it (the query) as a source for a **view**, then every time you select from a view, it reflects "new" data set.

Comment: When I run the data I don’t want to refresh the page I want the data refreshed automatically and bring data depend on this where clause it’s possible

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Open chart's property palette, navigate to its "Attributes" and scroll down to **Automatic Refresh** section which lets you enter interval (measured in seconds). Apex will then ... well, automatically refresh the chart, reflecting data returned by such a WHERE clause.

Comment: Really thank you, you help me a lot after 2 days work , and if I want live data I use that same method

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you are saying.